# Input from file: "advanced" (using less-than sign) vs. "beginner" syntax

Tags: command-line, input

I read the following in the [grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1):

> A simple example is changing "day" in the "old" file to "night" in the "new" file:
>
> `sed s/day/night/ <old >new`
>
> Or another way (for UNIX beginners),
>
> `sed s/day/night/ old >new`

Why might the author consider the first form more advanced?

I mean, what are the advantages of using this form over the "beginner's" syntax?

Comment: There's no significant difference between the two. I would disagree with the classification "for UNIX beginners". If anything, I'd prefer the second form because it takes less typing and is equally clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One advantage to allowing the shell to do the `open()` like:

```
utility <in >out
```

as opposed to allowing the named utility to do the `open()` like:

```
utility in >out
```

...is that the file-descriptor is secured *before* the named utility is called, or else if there is an error encountered during the `open()`, the utility is never called at all. This is the best way to guard against side-effects of possible race conditions - as can happen from time to time when working with *streams* and the *stream editor*.

If a redirection fails, the shell short-circuits the call to the utility and writes an error message to stderr - the *shell's* stderr and not whatever you might have temporarily directed it to for the utility *(well, that depends on the command-line order of redirections as well)* - in a standard diagnostic format. The most simple way to test if you can open a file is to open it, and `<` does that implicitly before anything else.

Probably the most obvious race condition indicated in the commands in your question involves the *out* redirection. In both forms the shell does the `>` write open as well and this happens regardless of whether `sed` can successfully open the readfile in the second form. So *out* gets truncated - and possibly needlessly. That could be bad if you only wanted to write your output if you could successfully open your input. That's not a problem, though, if you always open your input first, as is done in the first form.

---

Otherwise, there are at least *10* numerically referenced file descriptors that can be manipulated with shell redirection syntax in that way, and these combinations can get kind of hairy.

Also, when the shell does the open, the descriptor does not belong to the called command - as it does with the second version - but to the shell, and the called command only inherits it. It inherits in the same way any other commands called in the same compound command might be, and so commands can share input that way.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` takes file(s) to work on via both STDIN and as argument(s).

In the first form, `sed s/day/night/ <old`, you are using the input redirection operator to pass the contents of file `old` to `sed` via STDIN.

In the second form, `sed s/day/night/ old`, you are just passing the filename as an argument to `sed`.

Both are correct and will produce the same output.

I think the author meant that unless you are familiar with the standard streams and what they do, how to use the redirection operators properly, it might be a bit tough for new user's to get used to the first one but again this is just my opinion, we can't be sure what the Author is up to there.