# Difference between "cat" and "cat <"

Tags: io-redirection, cat

I was working through a tutorial and saw use of both `cat myfile.txt` and `cat < myfile.txt`. Is there a difference between these two sequences of commands? It seems both print the contents of a file to the shell.

Comment: Related: [When should I use input redirection?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756) (and (remotely) [Should I care about unnecessary cats?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225608))

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/a/1192464/295286 for difference on what syscalls are executed when these two commands are called

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In the first case, `cat` opens the file, and in the second case, the shell opens the file, passing it as `cat`'s standard input.

Technically, they could have different effects.  For instance, it would be possible to have a shell implementation that was more (or less) privileged than the `cat` program.  For that scenario, one might fail to open the file, while the other could.

That is not the usual scenario, but mentioned to point out that the shell and `cat` are not the same program.

Comment: Yes, and for example you can do `sudo cat myfile.txt`. But `sudo cat < myfile.txt` will not work if you don't have privileges to read the file.

Comment: Note that `ksh93` has `cat` builtin (not enabled by default unless you have `/opt/ast/bin` early in your `$PATH` though).

Comment: Some programs behave differently depending on whether they get a filename argument or stdin. For instance, `wc` will print the filename before the counts when given an argument.

Answer (score 22):

There is no major visible difference in your test case. The most obvious one would be the error message you get if there is no file named `myfile.txt` in the current directory, or if you are not allowed to read it.

In the former case, `cat` will complain and in the latter case, your shell will, clearly showing which process is trying to open the file, `cat` in the former one and the shell in the latter one.

```
$ cat myfile.txt
cat: myfile.txt: No such file or directory
$ cat < myfile.txt
ksh93: myfile.txt: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

In a more general case, a major difference is using redirections cannot be used to print the content of more than one file, which is after all the original purpose of the `cat` (i.e. **cat**enate) command. Note that the shell will anyway try to open all files passed as redirected input, but only actually pass the last one to `cat` unless you use `zsh` and its `multios` "zshism".

```
$ echo one > one
$ echo two > two
$ cat one two # cat opens one, shows one, opens two, shows two
one
two
$ cat < one < two # sh opens one then opens two, cat shows stdin (two)
two
$ rm one two
$ echo one > one
$ cat one two # cat opens and shows one, fails to open two
one
cat: two: No such file or directory
$ cat < one < two # the shell opens one then opens two, fails and 
                  # displays an error message, cat gets nothing on stdin
                  # so shows nothing
ksh93: two: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

On a standard system, the shell and `cat` have no difference in file access rights so both will succeed of fail equally. Using `sudo` to raise `cat`'s privileges will make a big difference in behavior, as Thomas Dickey reply and attached comments already suggested.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you really use use `ksh` of your own volition, and if so... *why*?

Comment: @cat - that question is obviously based in ignorance. [build it yourself](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256968/52934) and see.

Comment: @mikeserv that was intended to be flippant, not seriously rude, but fair enough, i suppose

Comment: @cat - i didnt suppose otherwise. ignorance is not a thing to be ashamed of - it is only a lack of knowledge. if you dont understand why someone might choose to use ksh93, then i can only assume it is because you've never used it. so i recommend you do. its worth trying, to be sure. and believe me when i tell you, that, compared to `bash`, `ksh93` is far and away the better shell. it's *the* shell, almost.

Comment: On Solaris 11, /bin/sh *is* actually ksh93 though it says sh in the error message.

Comment: @cat Yes, ksh93 is my personal choice whenever possible. What makes you think that might not have been the case?

Comment: @BjornMunch `/bin/sh` is a link to `ksh93` on Solaris 11. It is quite a common practice to create such links to whatever shell is selected by the OS editor to be the default one, e.g. `bash` on Red Hat, `dash` on Ubuntu, and `ksh88` on many commercial Unix. To display error messages, some of these shells will pick the name they have been called with, that explains the `/bin/sh` you got with Solaris 11.

Comment: As @mikeserv pointed out [elsewhere](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249804/#comment430086_249804), `cat < file1 > file2` has a very different effect from `cat file1 > file2` in the case where `file1` is unreadable or nonexistent.  (The latter form truncates `file2`; the former will not.)

Comment: @Wildcard - its better fleshed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245946/52934). This question is practically a duplicate, really. I didnt mention it before because it gets hard to find those among 1500 other answers...

Comment: @Wildcard and mikeserv thanks for pointing out the difference between `cat < file1 > file2` and `cat file1 > file2`. I just wish I had known that years ago.

Answer (score 7):

`cat myfile.txt` reads the file `myfile.txt` then prints it to the standard output.

`cat < myfile.txt` here `cat` isn't given any file(s) to open, so -like many Unix commands do- reads the data from the standard input, which is directed there from `file.txt` by the shell, and prints to standard output.

Answer (score 6):

[@Thomas Dickey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/105132/thomas-dickey)'s answer is brilliant.

I just want to add some obvious facts about the case of reading several files (loosely related to your question, but still):

- `cat <file1 <file2 <file3` will read only file3, at least in bash. (Actually, it depends on shell, but most shells will [dup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dup_%28system_call%29) every specified file to stdin, which causes the last one to effect.)
- `cat file1 file2 file3` will read all the specified files sequentially (actually *cat* is shortened form of the word *concatenate*).
- `cat file1 file2 file3 <file4 <file5 <file6` will read only file1, file2, file3 (as cat ignores stdin when filename arguments are passed).

  - <sub>`cat file1 file2 - file3 <file4 <file5 <file6` will read file1, file2, file6, file3 (as hyphen forces cat not to ignore stdin).</sub>

And about errors. In case of inability to [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_%28system_call%29) some of files specified as arguments (without `<`), cat will skip failed files (with outputting relevant message to stderr), but still read other files. In case of inability to open at least one of files specified as redirections (with `<`), shell won't even start cat (this occurs even for redirections actually not used by cat). <sub>In both cases erroneous exit code will be returned.</sub>

Comment: Note that in your first example `cat` will nevertheless open `file1` and `file2`, same with `file4` and `file5` in your third example. It will only show `file3`, resp. `file6` contents if these previous open instructions succeed.

Comment: @jlliagre, thanks, I didn't know that. Strace obviously proved your correctness. I corrected parenthesised text for cases 1 and 3a.

Answer (score 0):

We can use another command to notice the difference between:

```
wc –w food2.txt
```

Possible output:

```
6 food2.txt
```

The command tells the file name since it knows it (passed as an argument).

```
wc –w < food2.txt
```

Possible output:

```
6
```

The standard input is redirected to file `food2.txt` without the command knowing about the file's name.