# Difference in cat sth vs cat < sth

Tags: linux, command-line, cat

I realized that `cat sth` and `cat < sth` both happen to give same output. Are they the same?

Comment: See also [Input from file: “advanced” (using less-than sign) vs. “beginner” syntax](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245946)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're not completely identical.   In cases where it matters, the  redirection approach will generally give more annoying and obscure results (of course that might be what you want though).

```
$ cat < /proc/self/maps
$ cat /proc/self/maps
55c61257e000-55c61258a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1180143                    /usr/bin/cat
...
```

Or try grep, the search program

```
$ grep "grep" /proc/self/exe
Binary file /proc/self/exe matches
$ grep "grep" < /proc/self/exe
$
```

Bit of a cheat, but you're most likely to run into this when using `sudo`, to run commands with `root` access:

```
$ sudo cat < /etc/shadow
bash: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
$ sudo cat /etc/shadow
root:!::0:99999:7:::
....
```

Comment: Your sudo example makes an excellent point; it may be worth mentioning that the second method works because it is the super-user, as `sudo cat`, opening the file, while it is the non-super-user's shell in the first case that attempts and fails to open the file.

Answer (score 5):

`cat`'s job is it to con**cat**enate everything it gets and then to print it out on stdout yet often is used to print out the contents of a single file (which of course is just concatenating the contents of all the one files given to it and then writing it to stdout). stdout (standard output) is just programs usually write output data. (There are programs (like `dd`) which write their output data to stdout unless stated differently by parameters and there also is the standard error channel stderr which programs write to when an error occurs.)

`cat` can take data given to it via stdin (standard input) or data from files passed to it as parameters.

What you're doing with `cat sth` is to call `cat` with the single parameter `sth` telling `cat` to write everything in the file `sth` to stdout. You could add more file names and see that the content of the files is concatenated and then written to stdout.

`cat < sth` changes the stdin of `cat` to the contents of the file `sth` before calling `cat`. `cat` then just reads everything from its stdin and writes it to stdout.

In both cases, `cat` writes the contents of the file `sth` to stdout. You can read more about this [here](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php) and also type in `man cat` into a terminal to read the man page of `cat` describing what it does.

Note that the contents of `sth` are read by the user you are logged in as (who you are logged in as in the terminal is not necessarily who you are logged in as in the graphical session (if any)), whereas programs can be executed with different rights by writing `sudo` before them and then read with the rights of the user who executed them. This can lead to different outcomes because the user you are logged in as and the user you switch to with `sudo` (not necessarily `root`, you can specify otherwise) might have different access rights on the file you're trying to read from.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of `cat`, printing the file `sth` works just as
well using `cat sth` or `cat <sth`, because the `cat` command was
designed to either print all files given as command line parameters
(the `cat sth` case: `cat` will receive the string `sth` as a
parameter, and will open the file) or, if no files were given, print
standard input instead (the `cat <sth` case: the shell will honor the
redirect by opening `sth` and connecting it to `cat`'s standard
input).

So the behaviour being the same in both cases is specific to `cat`; it
may not work at all for commands designed to accept only one of
standard input or command line parameters. In other cases, the
behavior may be slightly different, since the command may not have
access to the file name when the data is obtained through standard
input; compare:

```
$ grep -H foo sth
sth:foo

$ grep -H foo <sth
(standard input):foo
```